# Зачем в языках программирования нужны let и var?

Tags: любой-язык

Я в основном пишу на Python и там перед объявлением переменной нет никакого var или let, однако во многих других есть. В связи с чем есть пара вопросов.

1. Зачем нужны данные ключевые слова?
2. Почему let чаще всего употребляется в качестве константы?(почему создатели языка не использовали слово const)

Comment: откуда вывод что _let **чаще всего** употребляется в качестве константы_?

Comment: в разных языках значение ключевых слов может разительно отличаться. Без уточнения конкретных языков - вопрос слишком широк

Comment: Ну... если так уже спрашивать, то выписывайте все языки в один столбец, и наличие let - c другой стороны. let есть в бейсик, js. let нету почти везде, в питоне, с, с++, с#, pascal, delphi, asmx86, sql(общий).

Comment: Поддерживаю Grundy. let чаще используется для присвоения (по крайней мере JS strict-mode, Basic).

Comment: Swift, Rust. Там константы. В swift переменные объявляются через var а в Rust надо mut добавить.

Comment: Касательно `JavaScript`  - директива `let` позволяет объявить локальную переменную с областью видимости, ограниченной текущим блоком кода . В отличие от ключевого слова `var`, которое объявляет переменную глобально или локально во всей функции, независимо от области блока.

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос: подобные ключевые слова задают особенности поведения переменной и ее доступности из разных частей кода (для обнаружения ошибок в именах переменных на этапе компиляции и для исключения случайного повреждения значений переменных из за того, что забыли, что какое то имя где то уже было использовано). На второй: а почему именно let интересует, разработчики языка вольны в названии того или иного поведения. в perl например бывают my, local и our

Comment: @nick_n_a - позанудствую: [let](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) таки есть в C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

давным-давно, когда компьютеры были большими, а типичная память у них была маленькой (16Кб, 8Кб, 4Кб и даже меньше) разработчики очень извращались, чтобы уместиться в маленькую память.

синтаксический разбор очень сильно упрощается, если все операторы синтаксически устроены одинаково:

```
оператор операнд [,операнд]
```

например, [Ассемблер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80)

но уже в первых поколениях языков от такого жесткого формата начали переходить к более свободным грамматикам и к более удобному для человека синтаксису. В частности, операнд для команды присвоения очень быстро стал необязательным.

например, [Basic](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA) с его ключевым словом LET

Поэтому подобные ключевые слова нужны были чтобы упростить синтаксические анализаторы языков "высокого уровня" и уложиться в жесткие ограничения того времени по памяти. После победы структурного стиля и повальной строгой типизации, объявлять переменные стали при помощи типов переменных. И вот теперь мы снова возвращаемся к автоматическим типам и операторам auto, var, val, let. Но уже с новым смыслом и новым содержанием.

---

Let мало где употребляется в контексте "констант". разве что в современных Джавах. Let - это скорее дань уважения Бейсику, где этот оператор означал операцию присвоения. Бейсик в свое время выполнял ту роль, которую сейчас выполняет Java - простой язык высокого уровня, не привязанный к архитектуре конретного железа. Бейсик оказал сильное влияние на ИТ. И, уж чего греха таить, поспособствовал значительному расширению числа программистов - "Каждая кухарка может кодить на Бейсике"